# How can I alter an application/json script within an html file before it executes?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, shuffle

I have an html file with a `<script type="application/json"></script>` inside it. I need to alter the json object within this script before the html file loads. How would I go about doing that? The json object looks something similar to this:

```
    <script type="application/json">
        {      
            "questionOptions": {
                "ques_1": {"type" : "YesNoQuestion","questionText": "messages.questions.1"},
                "ques_2": {"type" : "YesNoQuestion","questionText": "messages.questions.2"},
                "ques_3": {"type" : "YesNoQuestion","questionText": "messages.questions.3"},
                "ques_4": {"type" : "YesNoQuestion","questionText": "messages.questions.4"},
                "ques_5": {"type" : "YesNoQuestion","questionText": "messages.questions.5"}
            },
            "questions": [
                "ques_1",
                "ques_2",
                "ques_3",
                "ques_4",
                "ques_5"
           ],
           "persist": false,
           "intl": {
               "locales": "en-US",
               "messages": {
                   "questions": {
                       "1": "<img src='../images/img1.jpg'>",
                       "2": "<img src='../images/img2.jpg'>",
                       "3": "<img src='../images/img3.jpg'>",
                       "4": "<img src='../images/img4.jpg'>",
                       "5": "<img src='../images/img5.jpg'>"
                   },
                   "yes": "Similar",
                   "no": "Old",
                   "dragAndDrop": "<br><span class='preq'>Is the object old or similar?</span><br>Starting dragging the button down to see the picture. Drag and drop to your answer.",
                   "continue": "Click Next to continue",
                   "next": "Next",
                   "back": "Back",
                   "finish": "Finish",
                   "thankYou": "Thank you for completing this form."
                }
            }
         }
    </script>
```

I need to randomize the questionOptions, questions, and intl[messages][questions] but randomize them in the same way as they all match up by index in their given array to each other.

Help is much appreciated.

Edit: Added matching quotes.

Comment: First thing you need to do is fix your JSON, it's invalid.  Then you need to write some code yourself, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  I'll add an answer that should help you get started.

Comment: How is the JSON invalid?

Comment: Copy and paste it into an online JSON validator, it'll show you the issues.  For a start, you're missing the end quote for `type="application/json"`

Comment: Simple typo. Thanks for the edit @BluePill

Comment: Question: How is the data being turned into HTML?

Comment: Just finished making it work. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts here:

1. There isn't really a way to randomize things *before* the html file loads, unless you have control over what generates the JSON in the first place, which I'm guessing is hardcoded as shown.
2. `questionOptions` and `messages` are hashes. The order of their keys do not matter, so I don't see a point in randomizing how the keys are inserted and laid out.
3. Finally, `questions` is an array - this is probably the only thing you want to randomize (and hopefully there is some rendering to be done on the UI based on this array order?)

Here's a small piece of code you can add to the array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = this.length; i; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = this[i - 1];
        this[i - 1] = this[j];
        this[j] = x;
    }
    return this;
}
```

And you can then invoke it on any array you want to randomize, e.g.:

```
qdata.questions.shuffle(); //assuming you store that JSON in a variable called qdata
```

Comment: You could easily randomize the data before the HTML loads, simply by putting your `<script>` tag before the HTML `<body>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Small example of how to turn a JSON script block into live data and modify the original JSON before the document loads:

```html
<script type="application/json">{"foo":"bar"}
</script>
<script>
function randomizeData(data) { return { foo: "something else" }; }
var data;
(function() {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    if (scripts[i].type === "application/json") {
      data = JSON.parse(scripts[i].innerText);
      // manipulate/randomize your data here
      data = randomizeData(data);
      // change the JSON source to whatever you like
      scripts[i].innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
      break;
    }
  }
})();

document.write("The value of foo: "+data.foo);
</script>
<body>
</body>
```